# How to send zipped json inputs in JMeter POST request?

Tags: jmeter, zip

I have a xyz.zip file and it contains multiple json files. I have to send this zip file in Jmeter post request and read all the json files.

Please let me know any solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whether you want tho send this zip file? or the json file date from the zip file

Comment: I want to send the json file data from the zipped file. API input accepts only zip file. This zipped file has 3 different json files that needs to be read.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other file, using [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

1. Tick "Use multipart/form-data" box
2. Provide full or relative path to your .zip file and use correct "Parameter Name" matching the name of the relevant [`<input type="file">` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) at the page

   [image]

More information: [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter)